# Trust self-signed certificate CentOS 7

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, centos7, self-signed, ca

I am generating a self-signed certificate for a development server but I need it to be trusted in order to use some of the tools that will be using the certificate.

This is what I have tried:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -x509 -nodes -keyout /etc/ssl/private/server.key -new -out /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt -reqexts v3_req -extensions v3_req -config /vagrant/openssl.san.conf -sha256 -days 1825

ln --symbolic /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/server.crt

update-ca-trust extract
```

I tried grepping the `ca-bundle.crt` file for the contents of `server.crt` after running the update-ca-trust command but it wasn't there.

I have also tried copying the file instead of making a symlink but that did not work either.

The certificate is created correctly and works for Apache but it produces the self-signed error:

> ```
> [vagrant@localhost certs]$ curl --head https://localhost/
> curl: (60) Issuer certificate is invalid.
> More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
> ```

How can I trust my self-signed certificate on the command line on the server?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `update-ca-trust` accepts *only* certificates *marked as CA*. There is a X.509 extension called **Basic Constraints** which is used to mark whether a certificate belongs to a CA or not. `update-ca-trust` silently skips those not marked as CA.

Check your certificate for the CA constraint:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in <cert_file> | grep "CA:TRUE"
```

The `CA:TRUE` can be set using the [OpenSSL config](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/x509v3_config.html).

Answer (score 1):

I simply issue the following command and fill my private DNS name in Common Name section.

```
openssl req  -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes  -keyout ca.key -days 365 -out ca.crt
```

After the following commands, the self-signed certificate will be trust.

```
cp ca.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
update-ca-trust extract
```